# Child rows in DataTables using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to bind a child table with a parent table. I am not able to figure out how this can be done when the data for the child table is coming through an AJAX call which then creates a dynamic table.

I have followed [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Below is my code.

```
$('#myTable tbody).on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = $('#myTable').DataTable().row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it

            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row

            row.child(format()).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

function format() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("MyFunction", "Home")',
        data: { "Id": MyId },
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var list = data;
            $.each(list, function (index, item) {

                return '<table>.......<table />';

                //i need to loop across the list and create a dynamic table with tr and td


            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            var error = JSON.stringify(result);
            throw "Error...";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding those new rows to the existing table?

Comment: I added some static data just to start off and it worked fine. However, I am fetching the data from database and need to use the AJAX call. I am not able to format a `dynamic table` using the items in the list.

Comment: Instead of returning the rows into the other function, I would add them directly to the table.

Comment: I have followed this - https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Think about it this way -- what you're doing is trying to grab data at the point where you click the button.  What the datatables example does is grab all the data you need for both the main table display AND the detail section.  You're merely adding a div on click that has elements you've grabbed from DataTables data model.  So, abandon your ajax call, return all the data you need in the initial query, and on click, you'd simply display data that's already there.

Comment: @krillgar that won't work , the api needs to be able reproduce on sort and filter etc

Comment: make an html table in regular html page as template...then work backwards to put it into the format function string. May not be the easiest way to do it programatically but will get you started

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = $('#myTable').DataTable().row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it

        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        format(row.child);  // create new if not exist
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

and then the `format()` will be

```
function format(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        .... 
        //async: false, you can use async 
        success: function (data) {
            var list = data;
            var html = '';
            $.each(list, function (index, item) {
                ...
                //create <tr> <td> with loop
                html= '<tr><td>.......</tr>';
            });
            callback($('<table>' + html + '</table>')).show();
        },
        ...
    });
}
```

demo here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9gzagp2/)**

Comment: any fiddle for reference...?? or any link that can be an example for this..??

Comment: added fiddle to answer

Comment: @JAG saw ur jsfiddle. I want to include css part in html. How to do that? (m new to web). kindly answer.

Comment: u can jus add css class to table like `callback($('<table class="some css class">' + html + '</table>')).show();`

Comment: Best example for this case. Extremely useful fiddle. Many thanks.